# javascript chrome extenstion: adding elements or strings to Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

im writing a litell form filler as Chrome Extenstion, and 1 of the text fields is a iframe.

im trying to add some string the iframe body tags.

this is how the site `Iframe` html code look like, afther the page is loaded (got it from chrome devlopers tools `F12`):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="wysiwygtextfield" style="height: 100px; width: 600px; ">
 #document
 <html>
   <head> </head>
   <body>
     <br/>
   </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

now my `Content Script` to try to add some string to the body:

```
 if ($("#wysiwygtextfield").contents().find("body").length > 0) {
    var body = $("#wysiwygtextfield").contents().find("body").val("some msg");
}
```

i tried similer code without using jquery, but it still didnt work.

i read about `Same origin policy`, but im not sure it apply here. becuse, the script is runing on the client side. (or mybee im wrong).

is there somthing i can do about it?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: `val` is used for getting/setting values of form elements, for body element you should use `html` method instead.

Comment: put this comment in answer I WANT TO ACCEPT AND I LOVE U!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val` is used for getting/setting values of form elements, for body element you should use `html` method instead.

```
$("#wysiwygtextfield").contents().find("body").html("some msg")
```

Comment: thank u very much! i cant belive this was so simple. just need to wait 6 mintus to accept it.